# getting the list of friends and to know if they have my app installed or not

Tags: facebook, apache-flex, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Eclipse FDT to write a Flex application for facebook on a facebook page.
I want to be able to fetch the friends list of that same user and to distinguish between friends who installed the app and friends who didn't.

I searched on stackoverflow and I saw that users did that using the old REST API, the question is can I do that with graph api ?

if it's not possible using graph api at all... so how to do with REST API ?! :)

with the following request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token?XXX
```

I can fetch the list of friends of that user. but it doesn't provide a flag if my app is installed. what can I do exactly and how ?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two ways to do it, with the graph api and with fql.

Using the [graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) you can make a request to: *[/me/friends?fields=installed](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends%3Ffields%3Dinstalled)* which should return a list of users, the ones that have the app installed will have this form:

```
{
    "installed": true, 
    "id": "USER_ID"
}
```

The ones who don't have the app will be of this form:

```
{
    "id": "USER_ID"
}
```

With [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) use [this query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20not%20is_app_user%20and%20uid%20IN%20(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me())):

```
SELECT 
    uid
FROM 
    user 
WHERE 
    is_app_user 
    AND 
    uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Comment: I am facing an issue parsing the result of the above call. The graph object contains a FBGraphObjectArray ,i can not parse it because the interface is not exposed. Any idea how can i get around this?

Comment: I have no flex experience (I assume that it's what you're using) and so I can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905210/fb-friends-list-who-have-already-authenticated-the-same-application/22906608#22906608)

Hope this answer helps some one down the line.