# Facebook SDK iOS invite user without FBWebDialogs

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to get list of my friends from Facebook who are not users of my app, and be able to invite them.

Using `FBWebDialogs` I can pick users, but I'm wondering how foursquare did it?
Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is option of `frictionless requests`.
On Facebook developer site they mentioned in section of `Invites and Requests`

> We touched on a scenario where users exchange requests back and forth. If this scenario is typical in your game, it can be a bad user experience to force them through the request dialog every time they want to send a request. The solution for this is frictionless requests.
>   Frictionless requests let users send requests to friends from an app without having to click on a pop-up confirmation dialog. When sending a request to a friend, a user can authorize the app to send subsequent requests to the same friend without another dialog. This streamlines the process of sharing with friends.

For more reference see [Facebook Invites and Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-games/requests/)

Comment: Yea, but I want to avoid WebDialog :|

Comment: See, There is not any other graph api like getting user info without opening webview. So you need to open webview once if you use frictionless requests.

Comment: What about Foursquare example? They have special deal with Facebook?

Comment: I'll note that the app "circle" also does this (annoyingly and spammingly imo).  But, from what I ahve researched, frictionless requests is the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You are asking two questions here:

**How to invite Facebook friends without web dialogs?**

Unfortunately, the web dialogs you are referring to are the best way to send invites to friends. There was a time when we had to resort to ugly hacks just to get this functionality in applications. Facebook added this functionality to iOS SDK after developers created bug reports and were literally behind them.

**Get a list of friends who are not using the app and invite them**

Foursquare IMO is not using the requests API. What they do is, whenever somebody links their Facebook account to their Foursquare account they make a note of the users friends who are using/not using the app. This is possible if the user grants the app permissions.

Then in the invite screen, they simply build a UITableView with list of friends who they think are not using the app. When you tap Invite they will just send an email invitation and not the Facebook request you are referring to.

Answer (score 4):

I think FourSquare syncing the user's friend list(friend ids) to its own server.. Then after they are checking it to create the custom interface like the screen shot you shared.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I didn't get the question right, but from what I know after you tap the invite button on Foursquare the Facebook invite dialog (apprequest) will pop up.

In general this dialog will let you select friends if you didn't specify any friends ids before presenting it, or  show you the selected friends like in Foursquare example.
There is an API to get your FB friends, so it's possible for your server to check witch of then already has the app...

Answer (score 3):

I've been researching this for a while and the main solution I have found is frictionless requests, as Rahul Patel noted.  You can do a direct request to the graph API and [see who has your app installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471566/getting-the-list-of-friends-and-to-know-if-they-have-my-app-installed-or-not).

From there you could fairly easily implement any sort of filtering.  For example, using the [Friend Picker UI Control](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/friendpicker-ui-control/) and implementing the method `friendPickerViewController:shouldIncludeUser:` and checking against a list of facebook ids who are not on the app that you cache somewhere else in your application and actively update it (for example in a simple core data model that is updated when appDidFinishLaunching), returning no if the user is not displayed.  This would only allow users to select individuals who are not on the app, and then you could send a request to them under the hood with frictionless requests.

I do think that it is not a great idea to spam people, however, without at least allowing them to check the names of their friends, or see who they are.