# Restricting Facebook invite dialog to non-app users?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, fbwebdialogs

I am creating an iOS app where the user can invite their friends to use the app using Facebook SDK `[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:message:title:parameters:handler:` method. However, I don't want to show the users that already have the app. I know how to check if a user is an app user or not (using the Graph API, checking the `is_app_user` field), but how can I make the request dialog to exclude the users that are already users of my app to avoid confusion to the user? Is there any way to achieve this other than the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18583650/811405?